# Why do some pop-up ads redirect through multiple domains?

Tags: redirect, popup, ads

I noticed a lot of shady websites use ads with multiple redirects before showing the content of the ad.

I do not want to link to any of these (propably) illegal content distribution sites, but this effect is easily found when browsing through streaming sites for TV series and stuff like that.

Basically, it works like this:

- User interaction (mostly click) opens popup
- popup shows firstdomain.com without content
- redirects to seconddomain.com
- redirects to thirddomain.com
- ...
- finally shows the ad, often a legit one, but this varies from sports betting to adult social media

Is there any upside to these multiple redirects? And why are they set up this way?

Comment: IMHO each domain triggers its own ads.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to be thrown from one TDS to [another](https://blogs.forcepoint.com/security-labs/uncovering-malicious-traffic-direction-system-blackhat-tds)

> A TDS is a web based gate that is able to redirect users to various
>   content depending on who they are. A TDS is able to make a decision on
>   where to send a user based on criteria such as their geo-location,
>   browser, operating system, and whether or not they have been sent the
>   malicious content already. There are many legitimate uses of TDSes,
>   but there are also specific TDSes (Sutra, BlackOS, NinjaTDS etc.)
>   written for malware actors

Also from [here](https://www.securityartwork.es/2017/05/08/what-is-tds-traffic-director-system/):

> As discussed above, TDS are not malicious elements per se within the
>   Internet ecosystem, as they are very useful for the operation of
>   e-commerce and online marketing, but also constitute a good malware
>   distribution platform.

...

> To avoid detection and make it difficult to track these downloads, it
>   is possible to link several TDSs between them